# Get id from sharepoint url in visual web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i want to get id from sharepoint url in visual web part. something like this

```
http://server/Lists/listname/dispform.aspx?id=1
```

i only want to get the id which is 1 and assign GetItemById to use the id.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("url"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lists = web.Lists["Test"];
                SPListItem item = lists.GetItemById(1);

                {

                   string test = Convert.ToString( item["Title"]);
                    TextBox1.Text = test;
                    string test2 = Convert.ToString(item["Description"]);
                    TextBox2.Text = test2;
                    string test3 = Convert.ToString(item["Assigned To"]);
                    TextBox3.Text = test3;
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

From the above code i want to assign GetItemById's value according to the id displayed in url

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what im trying to accomplish is to display list values according to the id

Answer (score 2):

I think (based on url to display for of an item) you want ID of current item [SPContext.ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.listitem.aspx) :

```
var id = SPContext.Current.ListItem.ID
```

Comment: well that was easy. and im thinking ive to get the url and extract the id from there. thanks man!